# Creating a SiteSettings Content Part in Orchard

Tags: database, list, settings, orchardcms, record

I am trying to create a white list part for the site's settings that will allow an admin user to enter a list of urls that are considered "white listed". I'm having a problem with storing this information in the database though. When creating a new content type with information that belongs in the database you can use the following:

```
public class ShareBarSettingsPart : ContentPart<ShareBarSettingsPartRecord> {
    public string AddThisAccount {
        get { return Record.AddThisAccount; }
        set { Record.AddThisAccount = value; }
        }
    }
```

to set the value of AddThisAccount in the database. My problem is I need a list of urls in the database and not just a single item. I tried the following but it gives me an error:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Orchard.ContentManagement;
using Orchard.ContentManagement.Records;

namespace Speedbump.Models
{
    public class SpeedBumpSettingsRecord : ContentPartRecord
    {
        public virtual List<string> whiteList { get; set; }
    }

    public class SpeedBumpSettingsPart : ContentPart<SpeedBumpSettingsRecord>
    {
        public List<string> whiteList
        {
            get { return Record.whiteList; }
            set { Record.whiteList.Add(value); } //I need to be able to add a single record to the list here
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`List<string>` is not supported as a record property type. It doesn't matter however as you should never use a record for a site setting part. Use `Store` and `Retrieve` instead. Any existing settings part will give you an example.

Comment: Why then does Orchard's website say to use a record? http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Adding-custom-settings Seems weird. I'll look at the email module and implement mine in that manner. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I have the Whitelist settings working and I can save the setting but how do I retrieve what is in the whitelist? I tried the following but it doesn't work: string whitelist = WorkContext.CurrentSite.As<WhitelistSettingsPart>;

Comment: The Orchard documentation says to use a record because it's outdated and needs to be updated. You're almost there: the result of `As` is the part. You now need to get its `WhiteList` property. Side note: your property names don't respect the .NET naming conventions. They should be CamelCased.

Comment: I get an error stating the namespace WhiteListSettingsPart could not be found. Any ideas? string WhiteList = _contextAccessor.GetContext().CurrentSite.As<WhiteListSettingsPart>.WhiteList;

Comment: I'm trying to access the new settings in a separate module. I added a reference and using Whitelist.Models; to my module that is trying to access the information but now I get an error saying: Orchard.ContentManagement.ContentExtensions.As<T>(Orchard.ContentManagement.IContent) is a method which is not valid in the given context

Comment: Sorry I figured it out. I forgot the "()" after .As<WhiteListSettingsPart>